# Django: Создание суперпользователя в панели администратора

Tags: python, django

Хочу сделать так, чтобы админ смог сделать других пользователей тоже админами. Когда в панели администратора он ставит галочку у пользователя `Администратор`, и сохраняет, то тот пользователь не может зайти в админку. Почему пользователю не выдаются права администратора?

models.py

```py
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=35, verbose_name='Имя')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=35, blank=False, verbose_name='Фамилия')
    patronymic = models.CharField(max_length=35, blank=True, verbose_name='Отчество')
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=124, unique=True, verbose_name='Email')
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, verbose_name='Номер телефона')
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Дата рождения')
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Администратор')

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'phone_number']

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Пользователь'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Пользователи'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.first_name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

За доступ в django admin отвечает не поле `is_superuser`, а поле [is_staff](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_staff):

> is_staff
>
> Boolean. Designates whether this user can access the admin site.

Comment: А что если я хочу, чтобы пользователь смог делать все?

Comment: Позвольте ему все - ставьте оба поля True

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо